# slice of struct uses too much memory

Tags: algorithm, go, memory-management, breadth-first-search

I tried to solve [this](http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/520/B) problem with BFS, but for input "99 100" my program uses more than 260 Mb and online-judge system throws MEMORY_LIMIT_EXCEEDED. I guess the problem is the way I use QUEUE. So what do you think is the problem? And how should I solve it?

Here is my code. And thanks in advance!:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type pair struct {
    nn int
    dd int
}

func main() {
    var n, m int
    fmt.Scanf("%d%d", &n, &m)

    if n >= m {
        fmt.Println(n - m)
    } else {
        device := make([]pair, 1)
        device[0] = pair{n, 0}

        ans := 0
        for {
            // pop front element
            tmp := device[0]
            device = device[1:]

            if tmp.nn == m { // reached destination
                ans = tmp.dd
                break
            }

            // add neighbors to the queue
            device = append(device, pair{tmp.nn - 1, tmp.dd + 1})
            device = append(device, pair{tmp.nn * 2, tmp.dd + 1})
        }

        fmt.Println(ans)
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: More readable and working(ACCEPTED) code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type pair struct {
    location int
    dist     int
}

func main() {
    var n, m int
    fmt.Scanf("%d%d", &n, &m)

    if n >= m {
        fmt.Println(n - m)
    } else {
        visited := make([]bool, m+2)

        queue := make([]pair, 1)
        queue[0] = pair{n, 0}

        ans := 0
        visited[n] = true
        for {
            // pop front element
            tmp := queue[0]
            queue = queue[1:]

            // reached destination
            if tmp.location == m {
                ans = tmp.dist
                break
            }

            // add neighbors to the queue
            if tmp.location*2 <= m+1 && visited[tmp.location*2] == false {
                queue = append(queue, pair{tmp.location * 2, tmp.dist + 1})
                visited[tmp.location*2] = true
            }
            if tmp.location-1 >= 0 && visited[tmp.location-1] == false {
                queue = append(queue, pair{tmp.location - 1, tmp.dist + 1})
                visited[tmp.location-1] = true
            }
        }

        fmt.Println(ans)
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `copy(device[0:len(device)-1], device[1:]` instead of `device = device[1:]`. Your backing array might never get collected.

Comment: You can do some optimisations first by not adding number that is larger than `target` into the queue

Comment: @Volker I fixed some bugs of my program but `device = device[1:]` wasn't one of them. Because when I changed it to `copy(queue[0:len(queue)-1], queue[1:])` my working program gets TIME_LIMIT_EXCEEDED. So thank you for your good will.

Comment: @PhamTrung, first words of your answer was the key: I was not implementing BFS correctly. I added visited feature and got ACCEPTED. Thank you! But... Your second suggestion is partially correct, because we need to add m+1 to the queue because the step with m-1 could be the answer. And besides I already implement x-target in the first if statement (n-m). So thank you too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm is not BFS, because, you can visit the same state more than one.

For example, 4 -> 3 -> 6 and 4 -> 8 -> 7 -> 6, which 6 will end up to be processed twice.

Secondly, for number `x` that is greater than the `target`, the minimum number of step is always

```
x - target + step to reach x
```

so you should not add it into the queue.

By doing those two modifications, the space complexity will be limited to O(m) which should help you to solve the problem.

Sample code

```
ans := -1
dist := make([]int, m + 1)
q := make([]int,1)
q[0] = n

for i := 0; i < len(q); i++ {
    node := q[i]
    if node == m {
       if ans == -1 || ans > dist[m]{
          ans = dist[m]
       }
       break;
    }
    a := node*2
    b := node - 1
    if a >= m {
       if ans == -1 || ans > (1 + dist[node] + a - m) {
          ans = 1 + dist[node] + a - m
       }
    }else if dist[a] == 0 && a != n {
       q = append(q, a)
       dist[a] = 1 + dist[node]
    }
    if dist[b] == 0 && b != n {
       q = append(q, b)
       dist[b] = 1 + dist[node]
    } 
}
return ans
```

Comment: `dist := make(int[], m + 1)` should be `dist := make([]int, m + 1)`.

Comment: @leafbebop fixed

Comment: I accepted your answers, because it shows the MAIN BUG of my program. But your code did not get ACCEPTED and your second suggestion is not exactly true. But as I said, that is not the point. Cheers!

Comment: @EzizDurdyyev modified the answer, is the second suggestion correct now or I am missing smt?

Comment: @PhamTrung sir I dont understand what you are trying to do there but that doesnt matter anymore)).

Answer (score 0):

A first glance tell me that for each `dd` you have, there is going to be a `2^dd` elements in the queue. And with the answer expected to be larger than, say, 50, it is a guranteed memory limit exceed.

A very simple and common optimisation is to track the visted nodeds (`nn` in your case). Create a `map[int]bool` (since the `dd` is only increasing so there is no reason to record the value of last visted) and don't add to queue.

Another optimisation, as metioned in the comments, is no to add `nn` larger than `targets` into the queue. That is a little bit complicated, as you need to record a value `res = min(res, dd+nn-target)` where `nn` is the value larger than target and `dd` is the step to get to the value. You also want to break if current dd is larger then res.

**The code of the accepted answer has a bug**. It never tries to determine if `b` is smaller than zero. A runtime panic of index of range is likely to happen given a designed test case.